# Soft question: Should I learn multivariable calculus, while I want to pursue a career in pure math?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, soft-question

I am interested in pure mathematics.  I like more abstract topics like number theory, topology, etc.  I would like to know the benefits on learning multivariable calculus in relation to a pure mathematics career.  Specifically, should I learn it or not based on my interests and future career in mathematics mentioned?  Thank you.

Comment: There's a lot of topology that grows out of multivariable calculus.  So "yes", learn it.  Michael Spivak's "Calculus on Manifolds" is a nice little book that would show you the future.

Comment: Multivariable calculus is a pretty basic and standard lesson for any mathematician (or generally engineers etc). Of course it depends on the level you learn it, but yes, it's definite that it's a basic part of any mathematicians "portfolio".

Comment: Multivariable calculus is pure math. Full stop.

Comment: Isn't this a bit like asking whether you should know multiplication tables before studying Galois fields?

Comment: Even if you end up not using multivariable calculus on your future research, it is something very basic that every mathematician should know to some level.

Comment: Yes, because at some point you want to calculate examples.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Yes. Yes.

If you like topology and number theory you'll be likely approaching analytic number theory which uses multivariate calculus all the time. Now, the real question is "am I prepared to learn this? Does it make sense now?"